# Need to update column id using row_number()

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with `user_id` ,`user_name`, `rec` columns. I have another column as ID. I want to populate the ID as below.

| User_id | User_name | rec ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | rec 1 |
| 123 | ABC | rec1 1 |
| 123 | BCD | rec2 2 |
| 123 | BCD | rec3 2 |
| 134 | XYZ | rec1 1 |

I am not sure if this is possible, First it needs to find the unique `user_id` and its number of occurrences and then assign 1 to n number based on the occurrences but for a `user_id` if there are multiple records with same `user_name` then both rows should be updated with same id.

Previous this was achieved by `row_number()` by using `user_id` as partition where id would give 1 to n based on the `user_id` occurrence. ( Thanks to @MTO)

```
UPDATE table dst
SET id = (
           SELECT seq
           FROM   (
             SELECT row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as seq 
             FROM   test_csv
           ) src
           WHERE src.ROWID = dst.ROWID  
         );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
UPDATE test_csv dst
SET id = ( SELECT seq
           FROM   (
             SELECT dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by user_name)
                    as seq
             FROM   test_csv
           ) src
           WHERE src.ROWID = dst.ROWID
         );
```

or, using `MERGE`:

```sql
MERGE INTO test_csv dst
USING (
  SELECT dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by user_name)
         as seq
  FROM   test_csv
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET id = src.seq;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_csv (user_id, user_name, rec, id) AS
SELECT 123, 'ABC', 'rec', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'ABC', 'rec1', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'BCD', 'rec2', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'BCD', 'rec3', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 134, 'XYZ', 'rec1', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `UPDATE` or `MERGE` the table contains:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | REC | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | rec | 1 |
| 123 | ABC | rec1 | 1 |
| 123 | BCD | rec2 | 2 |
| 123 | BCD | rec3 | 2 |
| 134 | XYZ | rec1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_yNRtA2p)

Comment: Thanks @mto , this worked perfectly. I have started learning PL/SQL in the last 6 months and this group has helped me a lot in my queries.  Most of my questions were answered by you. Can you guide me how to learn about all these functions that are available. How to know there is a function available to get this done?

Comment: @nav The easiest way is to search the internet (provided you know the name or description of the thing you are searching for). You can also look at the [Oracle functions documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982) and see if there is an appropriate function there. Mostly though, it is something that comes with experience.

Comment: @mto Thanks. Query is working fine but for 1000 records, it took few seconds but as soon as the records in the table have gone up to 10k then it taking 15 -20 mins and for 50k, it took more than 1 hr and i had to stop it

Comment: @nav Updated with a `MERGE` statement that does the same thing and may be more efficient.

Comment: @mto this was much better but i have a application which predefines the statement as update table se t column = and i need to pass the sql query to it. I cannot use the merge statement in my scenario.. Is Dense_rank() function causes any performance issue ?

Comment: @nav The problem is probably the correlation between the `UPDATE` and the sub-query and that it is regenerating the sub-query for each row of the table; the `MERGE` would solve that by only generating the sub-query once.

Comment: @mto Yes, every row it is sub querying to update the id. Merge is a good option i see it is fast but with the limitation at the application side, i can't use this merge in update statement. Apart from dense_rank() to achieve this. Any other function which might help? i need to use that function directly in update statement.